# javascript and rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

Creating an update.js.erb, or edit.js.erb javascript file is connected to the rails 3 actions?

I'm new to rails 3 but know javascript.

If I add respond_to to each action to accept javascript, then will this code be called upon the action?

Thanks

Comment: can you post sample code, so that it could be understood better

Answer (score 2):

Unable to understand your question, but based on what I understand you might looking for this.

You can render `js` files using `render :js` like:

```ruby
render js: "$('#div_name').some_event;"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 you should set different respond types on the top of your controller class.
Something like this (probably it does not make any sense, but this is a dummy example):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base

  respond_to :html
  respond_to :xml, :json, :except => [ :edit ]
  respond_to :js, :only => [:create]

  def index
    respond_with(User.all)
  end
end
```

Then, you are responding using respond_with, and Rails will recognize type of request based on Accept header or request.format like (/users.json, /users.xml, etc.) and render proper files (index.html.erb, create.js.erb, etc.) depending on format

Answer (score 0):

"Creating an update.js.erb, or edit.js.erb javascript file is connected to the rails 3 actions?" not necessarily, but it should be. conventionally, the file name should be the same as the method name. its a logical relation. but u can specify a file name(if the file name is different the method name) by

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :action => "different_action" }
end
```